# How to set centered text in a div that has aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm having a scenario where the text has to be centered into a div which should have aspect ratio. I do not want to use `aspect-ratio` as a lot of main browsers like safari do not support that.

Here is my code on what I've done now:

```css
.aspect-ratio-div{
   background-color: #f2f2f7;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 33.33%;
}

.text{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="aspect-ratio-div">
    <label>This is some centered text</label>
  </div>
</html>
```

This would work fine for images, as I have learnt but what about for texts?

This is the output which I would like..

[image]

the white space should be in 1:3 ratio and the text always in center of it.

What would be a good approach ??

I got what I wanted thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a few ways. Here are two.

`.text` does it with `display: flex;`
`.text-asbolute` does it with only absolute

```css
.aspect-ratio-div{
   background-color: #f2f2f7;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 33.33%;
}

.text{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

.text-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="aspect-ratio-div">
    <label class="text-absolute">This is some centered text</label>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `class to label` bcos you have use label in HTML and some changes in CSS

```css
.aspect-ratio-div{
   background-color: #f2f2f7;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 33.33%;
}

label{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="aspect-ratio-div">
    <label>This is some centered text</label>
  </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the result with some changes over your code to make it work... I used Flex instead of transform to aproach the solution... this way you will not have problems with multiline texts (if needed).

```css
.aspect-ratio-div{
   background-color: #f2f2f7;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 33.33%;
}

.text {
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="aspect-ratio-div">
    <label class="text">This is some centered text</label>
  </div>
</html>
```